# Skype for business web sdk 401 Unauthorised when trying to login

Tags: office365, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I'm trying to create an app using Skype for business web SDK.

Here is the part of login code:

```
var config = {
    apiKey: 'a42fcebd-5b43-4b89-a065-74450fb91255', // SDK
    apiKeyCC: '9c967f6b-a846-4df2-b43d-5167e47d81e1' // SDK+UI
};

var Skype;
var app;
console.log(Skype);

Skype.initialize({ apiKey: config.apiKey }, function(api) {
    window.skypeWebAppCtor = api.application;
    window.skypeWebApp = new api.application();
    Application = api.application;
    app = new Application();
    console.log("app", app);
    skypeSignIn();
    window.skypeWebApp.signInManager.state.changed(function(state) {
        console.log("in",state);
    });
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log("cannot load the SDK");
});

var skypeSignIn = function() {
    app.signInManager.signIn({
        "client_id": "my-GUID", // GUID obtained from Azure app registration.
        "origins": ["https://webdir.online.lync.com/autodiscover/autodiscoverservice.svc/root"],
        "cors": true,
        "redirect_uri": 'https://freshservice.com',
        "version": 'freshservice skype for business integration'
    }).then(function() {
        alert('Logged in!');
    });
```

When I try the above code it gives an error 401 on origin URL -

```
GET https://webdirin1.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user 401 (Unauthorized)
```

How can this be fixed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to get your app authorised using Azure Active Directory. This will return an access token which is then sent with every request. Without this access token, all requests would be unauthorised. To obtain the access token you can refer this resource on how to [Set up Skype Web SDK Online](http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2016/03/skype-web-sdk-online-setting-everything-up-step-by-step-guide/).

Then after your app is authorised, then you can use the Skype.Initialize and SignIn. This would actually sign you in to Skype For Business.

Apart from this, if you have already authorised, getting an unauthorised response from the server is normal. As the app first tries to log you in. Than if the server returns unauthorised, it then initiates the authorisation process.

Comment: Where should this access token be used ? I cannot find any reference to using the access token.

Comment: @SoorajChandran You don't have to worry about using the access token. The Skype Web SDK takes care of it and attaches the access token with every request automatically.

Comment: We were able to sign in the user through SDK. However we are trying to do the same thing using access token , so that the token can be persisted and the user doesn't have to login every time. Is this achievable ?

Comment: You don't need to. Once you are logged in, the next time you redirect to Azure, it will give you a new token which you will save and continue. Persisting the token will have you deal with extra scenarios, like checking if the token is expired and then trying to regenerate them in those cases.But as far as I know, you need to call sign in every time, because you cannot persists the Skype Application object.. So a new one should be accessed every time.

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet you shared above does not have any code to redirect the user to Azure Active Directory (AAD) so that the user can enter his credentials. This is ok if the user is already signed in to the browser, but otherwise you will need to redirect to AAD, allow the user to sign in, and once AAD redirects back to your application then call the `app.signInManager.signIn` method.

Check out this page for more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/developwebsdkappsforsfbonline

Ensure that the redirect uri that you provide is configured in your AAD application as a valid reply url.

During the process of sign in you are going to notice 401s. Each time that happens the sdk will redirect to AAD to obtain a token. If the user has already signed in then AAD should redirect back to the provided uri with an access token in the `location.hash` property.

Comment: I made the OAuth request and got the access token. How could I use this token in the request header to make an api request through sdk and sign in the user. Are there any documentation about this?